# Python packaging (passlib, argon2) for AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-lambda

I am trying to create a Python function for AWS Lambda that uses the [`passlib`](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library for password hashing with `argon2`.  To this end, I am using `pip` to install the following packages in a local directory, zipping them with my Python file, and uploading to Lambda:

```
passlib==1.7.1
argon2-cffi==18.1.0
cffi==1.11.5
pycparser==2.18
six==1.11.0
```

These packages are sufficient to let me use `argon2` through `passlib` on my local Ubuntu environment.  However, I keep getting the following error when testing in Lambda:

```
  File "/var/task/my-function.py", line 41, in handler
    if argon2.verify(password, hash):
  File "/var/task/passlib/handlers/argon2.py", line 525, in verify
    cls._stub_requires_backend()
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2221, in _stub_requires_backend
    cls.set_backend()
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2143, in set_backend
    raise default_error
passlib.exc.MissingBackendError: argon2: no backends available -- recommend you install one (e.g. 'pip install argon2_cffi')
```

In the Lambda console, it appears that everything is uploading as expected.

I would ideally like to know how to correctly package my Python application for Lambda, but would also accept other ways of doing `argon2` or `bcrypt` password hashing and hash verification in Lambda.  Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't including all of the required files when I was creating my .zip archive, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963857/import-error-from-cyptography-hazmat-bindings-constant-time-import-lib

In the process of debugging, I created an Amazon Linux environment to install/compile libraries for maximum Lambda compatibility.  So my process for packaging Lambda functions now looks like this:

1. Spin up an Amazon Linux environment (e.g. Docker).
2. Use `yum` to install `zip`, `libffi-devel`, desired Python version (I used `python36`), and `virtualenv`.
3. Create and activate a virtual environment.  Install all Python packages with `pip`.
4. Create a .zip archive including the Lambda function and all site packages from the virtual environment.  For example:

   ```
   zip -9 lambda.zip myfunction.py
   cd venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
   zip -r9 ../../../../lambda.zip .
   cd ../../../lib64/python3.6/site-packages/
   zip -r9 ../../../../lambda.zip
   ```
5. Upload `lambda.zip` to AWS Lambda.